# Downloading an eSIM programatically in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, euiccmanager

I am trying to download an eSIM programatically in Kotlin.

```
val sub = DownloadableSubscription
                .forActivationCode(code /* encodedActivationCode*/)
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION)
        val callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0 /* requestCode */, intent,
               PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        try {
            mgr.downloadSubscription(sub, true, callbackIntent)
            Log.e(TAG_ESIM, "HERE DLOAD")
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            Log.e(TAG_ESIM, e.toString())
        }
```

I am using the code above `downloadSubscription`
and the logs displayed is this:
`Multiple enabled profiles is not supported, return default port index downloadSubscription cardId: 0 switchAfterDownload: true portIndex: 0 forceDeactivateSim: false callingPackage: <package_name> isConsentNeededToResolvePortIndex: false shouldResolvePortIndex:true`
`Caller can't manage subscription on target SIM or  User consent is required for resolving port index. Ask user's consent first`

I added this in AndroidManifest.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTIONS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />`

When I tried calling this:
`Log.d(TAG_ESIM, mgr.euiccInfo.toString())`

[This is the logs displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOAUy.png)

Does it need to have a setup for slotId or something I missed with regards to the permission or config?

Comment: Did you finally make it?